# Regex: Match variable amount of characters based on previous group length

Tags: regex, grep, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am in search for a regex(an *(e)grep* regex) to match the following string; the pattern is *"lesser than or equal amount of `E`'s than in the previous set of `E`'s."*

**Example:**

Should match: `EEEEEEE EEE EE EE E`

Should not match: `E EE EE E EEEE`

I was thinking of trying something with negation but that didn't work out as expected..

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail? What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Working in (e)grep, added that sorry. I tried doing something like
(E*)\s(\1)E*\s(\2)E* (and so on) for reverse; but then found out that that wasn't going to be the solution as I don't know the length of the string and it seemed wrong anyways

Comment: Do you know how many groups of E characters there are in the given string?

Comment: no, that's why my approach wasn't going to work out.

Comment: this was a question at an exam and only grep/egrep can be used @stribizhev, so it must be possible somehow

Comment: Not sure if that works in egrep, but wouldn't this work: `^((?!\b(E+) \2E+)[E ])+$` ?

Comment: @L3viathan grep says it's an invalid backreference; however in regexr it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 'EEEEEEE EEE EE EE E' | egrep -v '\b(E+)\b.*\1E' # => EEEEEEE EEE EE EE E
echo 'E EE EE E EEEE' | egrep -v '\b(E+)\b.*\1E' # => no matches
```

The idea is that after taking a complete sequence of `E`s (`\b(E+)\b`), there shouldn't be another occurrence of the same sequence plus another `E` (`\1E`). Obviously, we use `-v` for negation.